# ERROR: How could i fix this issue with parameter passing?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::exit;
using std::string;

void pin(double &Balance);
void menu(double &Balance);
void helpMenu();
void withdraw(double &Balance);
void deposit(double &Balance);
void overdraft(double &Balance);
void overdraftMenu(double &Balance);
void viewBalance(double &Balance);
void BuisnessOverdraft(double &Balance);
void OverFiveOverdraft(double &Balance);
void UnderFiveOverdraft(double &Balance);


int main()
{   
    double Balance;
    pin(Balance);
    return 0;
}

void pin(double &Balance)
{
    int AccountPin = 8376;
    int AttemptNum = 0;
    int Pin;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter your pin: ";
        cin >> Pin;
        if (Pin == AccountPin)
        {
            menu(Balance);
        } 
        else
        {
            cout << "Wrong pin, please try again." << endl;
            AttemptNum++;
        }
    } while (AttemptNum < 3);
    cout << "You have used all of your attempts, you can no longer attempt with this card" << endl;
    return;
}

void menu(double &Balance)
{
    int choice;

    do {
        cout << "Please choose from these options:\n1: Withdraw\n2: Deposit\n3: View balance\n4: Apply for an Overdraft\n5: Help menu\n6: Exit\nPlease choose between 1 and 6: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            withdraw(Balance);
            break;
        case 2:
            deposit(Balance);
            break;
        case 3:
            viewBalance(Balance);
            break;
        case 4:
            overdraftMenu(Balance);
            break;
        case 5:
            helpMenu();
            break;
        case 6:
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please try again" << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (choice < 0 || choice > 6);
}

void helpMenu()
{
    cout << endl << "When prompted by the interface please input a number between the numbers it says.\nYou cannot withdraw more than £200\nIf you have nothing left in your account you can apply for a overdraft" << endl << endl;
    return;
}

void withdraw(double &Balance)
{   
    double withdraw;
    cout << "How much would you like to withdraw: ";
    cin >> withdraw;
    menu(Balance);
    Balance = Balance - withdraw;
    if (Balance < 0) {
        cout << "You need to apply for an overdraft" << endl;
        Balance =- withdraw;
    }
    return;
}

void deposit(double &Balance)
{
    double deposit;
    cout << "How much you like to deposit: ";
    cin >> deposit;
    menu(Balance);
    Balance =+ deposit;
    return;
}

void viewBalance(double &Balance)
{
    menu(Balance);
    double balance = Balance;
    cout << "You have " << char(156) << balance <<  " in your bank account" << endl;
    return;
}
void overdraftMenu(double &Balance)
{
    char choice;
    do {
        cout << "Would you like to apply for a overdraft, yes or no? ";
        cin >> choice;
        tolower(choice);
        if (choice == 'y') {
            overdraft(Balance);
        }
        else if (choice == 'n') {
            return;
        }
        else cout << "Please try again";
    } while (choice != 'y' || choice != 'n');
}

void overdraft(double &Balance)
{
    int choice;
    do {
        cout << "Are you:\n1: A buisness owner\n2: A customer of over 5 years\n3: A customer of under 5 years\nPlease enter a number between 1 and 3";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            BuisnessOverdraft(Balance);
            break;
        case 2:
            OverFiveOverdraft(Balance);
            break;
        case 3:
            UnderFiveOverdraft(Balance);
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Input a correct value\nPlease try again";
            break;
        }
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 3);
}


void BuisnessOverdraft(double &Balance)
{
}

void OverFiveOverdraft(double &Balance)
{
}

void UnderFiveOverdraft(double &Balance)
{
}
```

I am creating a ATM program for school work and I need to use parameter passing to get the balance value and deposit, withdraw and apply for overdraft. however when I run the code and then deposit the balance doesn't increase. I also need to add a system for saving a users details like name, and account details this will need to be saved to a text file.

Comment: What is the question? Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: Variable names are case sensitive. `Balance` is not `balance`. In your program, `Balance` is uninitialized when you pass it to your function, and it's never changed inside the function, so its value could be anything. You also don't pass it from your pin function to the menu, so there's no way any change could be made to the variable declared in main.

Comment: What is the value of `balance` each time? And Where do you want to increment it?

Comment: Try changing `double balance = 1000;` to `Balance = 1000;`

Comment: afaik a variable can only be initalized once after that it can only be assigned to but not "reinitialized"

Comment: so just remove `double balance = 1000;` and write directly: `Balance = 1000`. Remember that C++ is case sensitive so `Balance` is not `balance`.

Comment: If the `pin` is determined to be correct, you are calling `menu` instead of returning to go back to the function that called `pin`. Therefore, any operations after calling `pin` never get done, such as `Balance = Balance + deposit` to add to the balance.

Comment: Mark, could you elaborate on that, since the menu does get called and it goes to the other functions such as deposit and withdraw.

Comment: You don't pass a variable to menu, so how could anything in menu change that variable? Since you tagged this C++, have you considered a class to store your data and allow member functions to modify it? What you're creating here is a recursive spaghetti mess.

Comment: `Balance = 1000.0;` will reset the value of the variable given to `void balance(double&)` to 1000 each time it's called. It seems you are under the impression the function binds the argument it's given to some object with an initial state of 1000. This is not how c++ works. `double & Balance` will simply refer to the variable given as arguments to the function and set that variable to 1000.

Comment: Francois I have just reached that conclusion how would be the best way to change that. Also @RetiredNinja know how to use classes however the exercise has to be done in one file, which is really annoying it also has to be in the procedural paradigm as well.

Comment: @RageGames you can use as many classes as you want in one file. But what you really need to do is pass the state (balance in this case) around to the functions that need to read or modify it. The balance should be defined in *one* place, not once in each function.

Comment: @RageGames You edited your code and now only call `pin` once, so the issue is no longer present.

Comment: Procedural doesn't mean infinitely recursive. Have each function do its work and return the data necessary, either by return value or reference, but return to the menu and then call another function. Get rid of the recursiveness.

Comment: @Mark I have fixed part of the issue however, now I'm struggling with getting the value to stay the same I what I should do but not how I do it. I need to get my balance to change when I withdraw or deposit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some correction here. First of all you are using local variable which are local to your function and once control return from the function, this local variable values will no longer available. First learn about global variable and local variable. Better you should use a structure like

```
          customer{
                      char customerName[200];
                  double balance = 0;
                  };
```

If you don’t know about structure declaration and use it better learn it first.

I am just modifying your code to fix it temporarily.

```
 double Balance = 1000.00; 
 int main()
 {
 }
 //declare Balance as global variable just above your main function.

 //modify your balance method like below
 void balance(double & balance)
 {
    balance = Balance;
 }

void deposit()
{
    double deposit;
    //double balance;//this is your local variable
    cout << "How much you like to deposit: ";
    cin >> deposit;
    //balance(balance);
    //Balance = balance + deposit; 
    //here in above Balance is your global variable   
    //better use a setBalance() method like below
    setBalance(deposit);
    menu();
}

void setBalance(double deposit)
{
    Balance = Balance + balance;
}
//This is your new method
```

This will fix your issue. But still it is not even upto the mark. Regarding storing the value in the file just learn how to create and read/write file in C++ or C. First try by yourself. If you face any trouble we can help you on that.

GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, you define Balance as a local variable. It means it's not valid outside of function body => it's destroyed.

Simplest solution - if acceptable, and if i understand your problem correctly - is that you make it global (and of course remove local definitions).

**Global not a possibility:**

Then you need to pass Balance to every func by reference. 
First example of function defition:

```
void pin(double& Balance){ .... }
```

Call it like:

```
int main()
{
   double Balance;
   ...
   pin(Balance);
   ...
}
```

From pin you call menu, so you must do the same for menu():

```
void menu(double& Balance) { ... }
```

And modify every function you call from menu the same way.

**Next** Remove all local definitions of

```
double Balance;
```

!!BUT!! - leave it only in main()

Comment: yes making it global would work but I've been told not too use it for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You have several major flaws in your code:

- You should not call `menu()` at the end of every function - this causes recursion. Just `return` from the functions and the `do while` loop will continue to iterate.
- Your loop in `menu` has the wrong condition. You can do `while(true)` and `return` on `case 6` or you can do `while (choice != 6)`. You do not need to do `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` there. This way, it will return control to `main` and exit the program properly.
- Do not declare `Balance` locally in functions. Declare it only once (`menu` looks like a good place) and pass it as a reference to every function that needs it.

Comment: The break statements in the switch are necessary and do not break the outer loop, only the switch. https://ideone.com/Pql1u5

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what I was thinking last night - removed that point.